# Wrong sorting of items with repeated timestamps in agenda view?

Tags: emacs, org-mode, date-sorting

I am using Emacs org-mode.  Assume it is 2012-11-10 (today) and I have a TODO item:

```
**** LATER [#D] call John                       :phone:
     SCHEDULED: <2012-07-23 Mon .+1m>
     - State "DONE"       from "TODO"       [2012-06-23 Sat 12:21]
     :PROPERTIES:
     :LAST_REPEAT: [2012-06-23 Sat 12:21]
     :END:
```

In the agenda view that I get with <kbd>Ctrl-c</kbd> <kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>a</kbd> this shows up as:

```
  TODO:       Sched.19x:  LATER [#D] call John                      :phone:
```

and is sorted among the other items that have a `SCHEDULED` date 19 days ago.  However, the item above has not been worked on for almost four months, so it should actually be sorted among the items `SCHEDULED` on <2012-07-23 Mon> (~110 days ago).

I consider this a bug, but I wanted to know whether there is any option I could try to fix that behavior.  I have searched the internet for over an hour but did not find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a bug but the expected behavior.

You scheduled the task with the repeated interval

SCHEDULED: <2012-07-23 Mon **.+1m**>

which means that the task is kinda re-scheduled every month. The last time it was 2012-10-27, 19 days ago.

You can remove the repeated interval

```
SCHEDULED: <2012-07-23 Mon>
```

then the task will be shown as scheduled 110 days ago.

Comment: Dear Oleg, thanks for the reply.  The behavior might be the intended one, but I didn't expect it.  And I think one can have different opinions on what is reasonable.  I like the way the agenda view sorts items by importance, where one criterion is the time I haven't worked on it.  An item that should be repeated once a week but hasn't been worked on for months should be high up in the list and not low, I think.  Thus, it would be nice at least to have an option for that.  Josef.